# What's the control stucture "if true, then return" called?

Tags: if-statement

I remember a fellow programmer had a name for the kind if statement that returns out of the method it's in if it evaluates to true.

What's that called, again? Like, a "conditional shield," or something?

It's very helpful for reducing conditional nesting.

Comment: I don't know what it is called, but I like the sound of `conditional shield`. Although I don't think it says what it does.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you mean, but if true always evaluates, so if true, then return would be equivalent to just return. On a related note, I sometimes find it useful to use if False for quick and dirty commenting out a block of code.

Comment: [`sanity check`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanity_testing)?

Comment: I've generally heard "conditional guard". But I'm not sure there's a *standard* term for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've heard "guard condition" to describe the check and "bail out [early]" to describe the action of returning before the main action.

Comment: I also know this term to be used to describe this situation.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard it get called an *early return*. Compilers have been known to generate suboptimal code for early returns in some cases, such as when returning object types.